# Error 1004 : autofill method of range class failed vba excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I am running the below VBA code -

```
lastColumn = Cells(5, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
count_dates = Range("H2").Value

Set cellSource = Range(Cells(6, 13).Address)
Set cellTarget = Range(Cells(6, 13), Cells(count_dates + 5, lastColumn))
cellSource.AutoFill Destination:=cellTarget, Type:=xlFillDefault
```

The code is running perfectly fine on one PC (Excel 2016), but not running on the other (Excel 2010). I am unable to figure out the reason for the same.

The cell (6,13) has a formula which i want to drag both horizontally right and vertically down

The error I get is -
    Error 1004 : Autofill method of range class failed

Comment: are you basically doing Range(Cells(6, 13), Cells(count_dates + 5, lastColumn)) = Range(Cells(6, 13))? If so, simply re-write to avoid AutoFill.

Comment: `Range(Cells(6, 13).Address)` is exactly the same as `Cells(6, 13)` ... what you are doing is calculating the address of the `cells(6,13)` range then you are referring to the range at that address.  .... sort of like `i want to go to the house that is at the address of the house where Richard lives` instead of `i want to go to Richard's house`

Comment: You should tell us what data is in the autofilled cells so we can reproduce this.

Comment: @Akshat Agrawal what is value of `LastColumn` and `Count_Dates`

Comment: Have editted the question to make it clearer and remove ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2010 Autofill works in a single direction only, either horizontal or vertical. Therefore, if you wish to fill a 2-dimensional range you should first fill one row horizontally (including the source cell) and then use that row as source copy the entire row down. The code below does that.

```
Sub AutoFillRange()

    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim count_Dates As Long
    Dim cellSource As Range, cellTarget As Range

    lastColumn = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    count_Dates = Range("H2").Value

    Set cellSource = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, "M")
    If lastColumn <> cellSource.Column Then
        ' return an unexpected result if lastColumn is smaller than cellSource.Column
        Set cellTarget = cellSource.Resize(1, Abs(lastColumn - cellSource.Column + 1))
        cellSource.AutoFill Destination:=cellTarget, Type:=xlFillDefault
        Set cellSource = cellTarget
    End If
    Set cellTarget = cellSource.Resize(count_Dates, cellSource.Columns.Count)
    cellSource.AutoFill Destination:=cellTarget, Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```